# A Schwartz function is identically zero on $\mathbb R^2$ if its integral on every line in the plane is zero

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

If the integral of a Schwartz  function is zero on every line in the plane  then it is zero.

I think maybe Fourier transform in one variable is useful. But I can't success.

Is there any hint to prove this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, note that $$\hat f(0,t)=\int_{\Bbb R}\left(\int_{\Bbb R} f(x,y)e^{-ity}\,dx\right)\,dy=\int_{\Bbb R}0\,dy=0$$

There are various ways you could modify this to show $\hat f(s,t)=0$. The most fun is this: If $O$ is an orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrix (or rather the linear transformation defined by such a matrix)  then $$\widehat{f\circ O}=\hat f\circ O.$$

---

That last bit about the orthogonal transformation is a standard thing. But since I stated it incorrectly at first I might give a proof. We're going to shift notation, taking $x,\xi\in\Bbb R^2$, so that, after inserting the $\pi$'s as in your favorite normalization for the Fourier transform, $$\hat f(\xi)=\int_{\Bbb R^2}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx.$$ Since Lebesgue measure is rotation-invariant and $O^{-1}=O^T$ we see $$\int f(Ox)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx=\int f(x)e^{-i(O^Tx)\cdot\xi}\,dx=\int f(x)e^{-ix\cdot(O\xi)}\,dx.$$

Comment: Is the $-$ supposed to be $=$?

Comment: Thx.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, given a typo or two...

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are vectors in $R^2$ then $(OX)\cdot Y=X\cdot(O^TY)$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you a lot. Would you please have a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585665/an-exercise-from-steins-fourier-analysis-about-wave-equation

Comment: I get the impression you're not really trying. See edit. To show that $\int_{\Bbb R}0=0$ note that $0$ is a simple function, and use the definition of the integral for simple functions.

Comment: Also note that $0x + ty=ty$.